# How to access the install4j custom application screens for a macOS app after 'first run'?

Tags: install4j

Install4j 9's [DMG media file](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/v/9.0/help/doc/concepts/mediaFiles.html#:%7E:text=To%20make%20it%20easier%20to%20use%20the%20screen%20and%20action%20system%20in%20install4j%20for%20installations%2C%20the%20media%20wizard%20allows%20you%20to%20select%20a%20custom%20installer%20application%20that%20is%20executed%20the%20first%20time%20the%20user%20starts%20the%20application%20bundle.) allows an installation wizard to be launched when the application shipped in the DMG is run for the first time, but there doesn't seem to be any way to access the custom install screens after that first run (for instance, to re-perform or undo some of the actions performed).

Is it possible to 'reset' the first run flag, or somehow pass an argument that will allow someone to access the custom install screens after the application has been run for the first time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start a custom installer application with the API. To get a code snippet to do that, select the custom installer application in the Installer->Screens & Actions step, activate the "Launcher integration tab" and click on "Start integration wizard". The code snippet will look like this:

```
ApplicationLauncher.launchApplicationInProcess("594", null, null, 
     ApplicationLauncher.WindowMode.FRAME, null);
```